# PCRE in Snort rule "invalid" because of non group command "?:"

Tags: syntax, pcre, snort, mcafee

I want to implement a Snort rule in McAfee NSM.
But I get the Error "Validation failed: Invalid or unsupported PCRE token:pcre: /^(?:GET|POST) /(?:watch|search|find|results|open|search|close)/\?(?:text=|from=|aq=|ai=|ags=|oe=|btnG=|oprnd=|utm=|channel=|itwm=)/
ERROR: Unsupported PCRE syntax.

When I delete all "?:" from the PCRE the syntax is valid.
What can I do to get this work?

Comment: PCRE supports `(?:...)` non-capturing groups. The issue is not related to PCRE.

Comment: So do you know how I can change it to work in NSM?

Comment: You yourself say *When I delete all "?:" from the PCRE the syntax is valid.* It is not clear what does not work.